# When to use "どうぞよろしくお願{ねが}い致{いた}します。" in a greeting?

Tags: set-phrases

Once the context is that we are about to part ways, when I want to say "goodbye" to someone in maximum 敬語{けいご}, I say「どうぞよろしくお願い致します。それでは、失礼いたします。」.

Is that usage of 「どうぞよろしくお願い致します」 correct?
Is 「どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます」 also ok? Is the nuance different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are saying good-bye to someone to whom you have just made a request, yes, you can say 「どうぞよろしくお[願]{ねが}いいたします。それでは、[失礼]{しつれい}いたします。」

We often say EXACTLY that in business settings.  Quite a few adult speakers would actually speak like that even in non-business occasions, but even for those people, the phrase would be too formal to use with close friends.

Less formal versions:

「よろしくお願いします。では失礼します。」

「よろしく～。じゃあねえ！」

Regarding 「どうぞよろしくお願い[申]{もう}し上げます。」, it is one step more formal than 「どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。」  It can still be used verbally in business, but it would mostly be reserved for writing.  The two phrases have exactly the same meaning.  It is just that the former raises the status level of the other person higher than the latter does.

Answer (score 2):

In ascending order of politeness:

> よろしく (friendly, very informal)
>
> よろしくお願いします (friendly and business OK)
>
> どうぞ、よろしくお願いします (formal and friendly)
>
> どうぞ、よろしくお願い致します (formal, addressee is above you in status)
>
> どうぞ、よろしくお願い申し上げます (very formal, addressee is far above you in status or you are addressing a group)

To make yourself sound more formal (as in writing a business letter or talking to the Shogun) you can replace 「どうぞ」 with 「[何卒]{なに・とぞ}」.

Comment: Just saying "よろしく" seems a little too pregnant to me. You are kind of leaving me hanging with just an inflected adjective. "よろしくね" would be more of a complete thought? The "ね" let's me know you are done with your statement?

Comment: Yeah, adding 語尾 like 「ね」 is good idea if you want to put that flavor in the mix. I was thinking about when it's said with a bit of inflection all by itself in casual speech, maybe as an abbreviation for 「よろしく頼んだぞ」 or 「よろしくお伝えください」. Besides you get a lot of that hanging-pregnant stuff in Japanese anyway with phrases like 「よいお年を」 , 「ご検討を」, 「いざ、イスカンダルへ」, 「し・ず・か・に！」 and things like that.